# Highchart world map rendering too slow in edge legacy browser

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Im facing issue in rendering highcharts world map in edge legacy browser. It's very slow to load.in Chrome and new MS Edge it works fine. Any ideas to improve the performance and to speed up the loading in Edge legacy browser.
Have zoom functionality. I have disabled mousewheelzoom and touchzoom

Comment: Hi @user2745698, Could you provide me with your chart configuration object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove any animations, transitions, and intervals from your code and see if it has any impact on performance. I would also follow the Network tab on the dev tools to make sure each API call is performed as expected in a reasonable time frame to rule out the aspect of a slow network.

Also, there is common auditing you can do on MS Edge sites to [Optimize website speed with Microsoft Edge DevTools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/devtools-guide-chromium/speed/get-started) give it a try to potentially find the root cause of your issue if none of the above helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. Tried with removing animation . Loading better.